# Valores do comboBox não aparecem para seleção

Tags: javafx

Gostaria da ajuda de vcs na seguinte questão!! Tenho um combobox e quero preenchê-lo com números inteiros. Acontece que quando executo o programa não aparece nada para eu selecionar!... Segue o código:

```
 ObservableList<Integer> options
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3);
 comboboxQuantCam.setItems(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está certo, exceto o objeto que não foi construído:

ComboBox comboboxQuantCam = new ComboBox();

Ficaria assim:

```
     ObservableList<Integer> options

        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3);

     ComboBox comboboxQuantCam = new ComboBox();

     comboboxQuantCam.setItems(options);

    seuLayout.getChildren().addAll(comboboxQuantCam);
```

Comment: Olá Carlos Ximendes, Boa Tarde! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!.. Na verdade eu construí o objeto, acontece que o id no SceneBuilder que estava errado:

 <ComboBox fx:id="comboboxEqUm"

Mas, muito obrigada pela atenção :)!

Comment: Obrigado, Sara Fernandes!